# LinearLayout issue for View in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have the following XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/array_name" />

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".PickemPicksheetActivity">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The issue is that the EditText does not display in the View at runtime?

What am I missing?

### UPDATE:

The following is the details that the recyclerView references:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/gamefield_background" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It seems that the EditText is under the FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update below code in your xml. It should be wrap_content, using match_parent it containing whole screen height

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical"> 
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PickemPicksheetActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/tp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="bottom" />
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I get the following error `AAPT: error: 'wrap_parent' is incompatible with attribute layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].`

Comment: i have update the code it should be wrap_content

Comment: Still does not display my EditText at the end of the recyclerView!?

Comment: And its still not.

Comment: update your edit text width as i have done in above code

Comment: It still doesn't work, I have put in an update about the framelayout being overlaid over the EditText

Comment: try to put your code inside scrollview if screen view is large